# Join two arrays in to one - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, arr

I am trying to merge arrays in to one.

```js
var newArray = ['11:30', '12:00','12:30', '13:00' ,'13:30', '14:00'];
result = ["10:00","16:00"];   // this is coming from my db
```

When i try to merge them i get 7 not sure why

```
var nameArr = timeBeenSelected.toString();
console.log(nameArr);
var nameArr2 = timeBeenSelected.split(',');
console.log(nameArr2);
console.log(newArray.push(result));
```

console.log(result); 
["10:00","16:00"]

console.log(newArray);
(6) ["11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

```js
var newArray = ['11:30', '12:00','12:30', '13:00' ,'13:30', '14:00'];
var result = ["10:00","16:00"]// Make sure whatever the data you are getting it should be JSON
//If it is in string just convert your result like as follows
//result=JSON.parse(result)

var finalResult = [...new Set([...newArray,...result])].sort()
console.log(finalResult)
```

Code Explanation

```js
[...newArray,...result]//This will return joined array
```

Above array can be duplicate results So I am using `new Set()` to get unique values.

```js
[...new Set([...newArray,...result])]
```

Now finally sorting the value using `sort() function` which is optional

Comment: Converting to set if multiple data exists

Comment: and again converting to array

Comment: then sorting if you need answer sorted

Comment: Sure @Ivar explained everything and updated the question

Comment: (14) [""", ",", "0", "1", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "6", ":", "[", "]"] i get this 
var output = [...new Set([...newArray,...result])].sort();

Comment: ohhh I know why you get this

Comment: you are getting result first do `result=JSON.parse(result)` ... And the apply this

Comment: @jibingeorge Check My Commented Code

Comment: [Array(8)]
0: (8) ["11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "10:00", "16:00"]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)


I get this

Comment: `[...new Set([...newArray,...result])].sort()` Do this and you will get proper

Comment: @jibingeorge This is what you want

Comment: can i ask why you told me to put JSON.parse(result

Comment: Yes because data which you are getting that was stringify data. and When you posted your output in comment, then from the output I got the error.

Answer (score 2):

Use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to combine arrays with each other.

```js
var nameArr = timeBeenSelected.toString();
console.log(nameArr);
var nameArr2 = timeBeenSelected.split(',');
console.log(nameArr2);
console.log(nameArr2.concat(result));
```

Comment: console.log(newArray.concat(result));
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: 11:30,12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30,14:00["10:00","16:00"] I get this

Answer (score 2):

```
array1 = ['a', 'b'];
array2 = ['c', 'd'];
```

classic js: Just concat two arrays.

### `array1.concat(array2)`

es6: you can take a glance destructering
example:

```
unifyArr = [...array1, ...array2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6, you can concatenate 2 arrays by

```
let newArray = ['11:30', '12:00','12:30', '13:00' ,'13:30', '14:00'];
let result = ["10:00","16:00"]
let combined = [..newArray,..result];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge both arrays using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) , Check the below snippet

```js
var newArray = ['11:30', '12:00','12:30', '13:00' ,'13:30', '14:00'];
var result = ["10:00","16:00"]

var output = [...newArray, ...result] //without mutating the input arrays 

console.log(output) // total 8 elements
```

Comment: (2) [Array(6), "["10:00","16:00"]"]
0: (6) ["11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00"]
1: "["10:00","16:00"]"
I get this

Comment: because you are not spreading it, you are doing like this var output = [newArray, result] , you need to spread it as shown in the answer , kindly check

Comment: did you Run code snippet, try running the code snippet you will be able to understand easily

Comment: running on the code snippet it works 
Do i put the dots? var output = [...newArray, ...result]

Comment: yes, as shown like in the answer, kindly vote and accept if it worked for you. Happy to help :)

Comment: If i do that i get (23) ["11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "[", """, "1", "0", ":", "0", "0", """, ",", """, "1", "6", ":", "0", "0", """, "]"]

Comment: did you checked the codesnippet posted in the answer ?

Comment: Yes that works but not when i run it with my code

Comment: the problem i think is you are spreading each character of result, is result is an array as same in the question you posted

Comment: i have updated the question i have added the result i get for result and newArray

Comment: is the result is an array , kindly check this Array.isArray(result), if it returns true then it is array ?

Comment: @jibingeorge kindly create a new question since its already closed one